# Ways to improve lower bounds while solving MIPs

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, cplex, gurobi, bounds

What are the ways to improve lower bounds while solving a minimization problem (MILP)?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Your question is broad. I recommended you explain your question in the detailed. It gives more chance to answer by the community. :)

Comment: One way is to use a very aggressive cut generation strategy.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "while".  Here is a now somewhat old paper on presolve, very pertinent to bound tightening techniques https://ampl.com/REFS/pripre.pdf .Or are you asking about getting better continuous relaxations during the solution process?

Comment: In addition to what was said above, also strong branching comes to mind. Note that some solvers provide a way to focus on raising that bound (for CPLEX see the MIP emphasis parameter).

Answer (score 1):

There are serveral strategies.
I recomend Lagrangian and Surrogate relaxation.

Look for James Davis video "2.6 lagrangian relaxation". I guess it would help.